# How to close docker environment from the outside world?

Tags: docker, jelastic

I have defined the following Jelastic configuration for my environment:

```
env:
  topology:
    nodes:
      - nodeGroup: bl 
        nodeType: nginx-dockerized
        tag: 1.14.2
        displayName: Node balancing
        count: 1
        fixedCloudlets: 1
        cloudlets: 4
        env:
          DOCKER_EXPOSED_PORT: 22,80,443
      - image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        count: 1
        cloudlets: 16
        nodeGroup: cp
      - nodeGroup: sqldb
```

Now, I want the users of my environment to access my docker application only through the load balancing node. From Jelastic's dashboard, I can't seem to configure any firewall rules for the cp node group. How can I close any connection to the Jenkins node from the outside world and only keep it open from the nginx node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see, your environment has a custom Docker as a cp layer, that's why UI Firewall is not available for your cp node group. More details are in [Container Firewall Rules Management](https://docs.jelastic.com/setting-custom-firewall) article.

Nevertheless, even if your cp layer is not a custom Docker but Jelastic certified dockerized template, UI Firewall will be available but you will not be able to close direct access to this node via [Shared Load Balancer](https://docs.jelastic.com/shared-load-balancer) anyway, due to internal limitations which will be improved in future releases. Some info you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55857428/how-do-i-disable-ingress-from-the-internet-to-jelastic-nodes/55972075#55972075)

Custom Docker, unlike other types of templates, has a full root access, so you can easily configure firewall with help of a command line.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a go and maybe post my solution here how I managed to configure the firewall "easily" (lol). Thanks for the insight provided for my problem! Now I know at least in what direction I can continue working.

Comment: Oh and yeah, I have other environments that use Jelastic certified dockerized template as the cp node. I tried to use the firewall UI to close access to them without any success. I was asking myself why there was such a UI if the functionality behind doesn't work at all...